# Why can't I set my button's shadow colour?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, shadow

I'm trying to set the shadow colour on a UIButton, but all I seem to be able to get is a mid grey.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 100);

[button setTitle:@"a" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:96]];

// set up the button colours 
button.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[button.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f)];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090825-xur3112ni5q2wrwwiix4jbcwc5.png](http://img.skitch.com/20090825-xur3112ni5q2wrwwiix4jbcwc5.png)

Am I setting the wrong property, or is it the way that I'm setting `shadowColor` that's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[button setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I was bashing my head trying to figure why it wasn't working.

Comment: Is there any way we can set shadow offset too?

Comment: shadow offset work as intended : [button.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f)];